# TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null when upgrading Angular2 to 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am upgrading an Ionic app to Angular 5.0.3. Unfortunately the app crashes on start giving the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at Content._readDimensions (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:36522:34)
    at dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:24444:9)
    at DomController._flush (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:24417:13)
    at rafCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:24410:22)
```

As far as I've been able to find out the error has something to do with the _readDimensions() function being unable to find a parent element on the ion-content element in my app.html. My app.html file looks like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
                {{p?.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "myApp: An Ionic project",
"config": {
    "ionic_rollup": "./src/config/rollup.config.js"
},
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "phonegap-plugin-push": {
            "SENDER_ID": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
    ]
}
}
```

I would be very happy if someone is able to help me out with this issue.

**Edit**
The app originally used these dependencies:

```
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^1.8.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "myApp: An Ionic project",
"config": {
    "ionic_rollup": "./src/config/rollup.config.js"
},
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "phonegap-plugin-push": {
            "SENDER_ID": "xxxx"
        }
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
    ]
}
}
```

**Edit**
The error seems to be connected with the Nav element and seems to be situated in my app.component.ts which looks like this

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {AlertController, IonicApp, Nav, Platform, ToastController, App, NavController} from "ionic-angular";
import {SplashScreen} from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
import {StatusBar} from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import {SecondPage} from "../pages/secondpage/secondpage";
import {FirstPage} from "../pages/firstpage/firstpage";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: NavController;

    public rootPage: any = SettingsPage;

    private backButtonPressedOnceToExit: boolean = false;

    pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;

    constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController, platform: Platform, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private ionicApp: IonicApp, private splashScreen: SplashScreen, private statusBar: StatusBar) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('key')) {
            this.rootPage = EarningsPage;
        }

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            console.log("platform ready");

            if (platform.is('cordova')) {
                /** not if testing browser */
                statusBar.styleDefault();
                splashScreen.hide();
            }

            this.pages = [
                {title: 'Page 1', component: FirstPage},
                {title: 'Page 2', component: SecondPage},
            ];

        });

        platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            [...]
        });
    }

    showToast() {
        [...]
    }

    openPage(page) {
        this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
    }

    }
```

The app crashes before I get to the platform ready event. The nav variable is undefined when I try to log it out in the constructor. I then get the following error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: parent.registerChildNav is not a function
    at new Nav (nav.js:67)
    at createClass (core.js:12449)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12284)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13742)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14176)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13770)
    at createRootView (core.js:13631)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14339)
View_MyApp_0 @ MyApp.html:19
```

Followed by an ERROR CONTEXT and the "Cannot read property 'children' of null" error.

Comment: Why jump 3 major versions but not up to latest?

Comment: Because it was the version used in the boilerplate apps. Upgrading to 5.2.5 doesn't help me though.

Comment: I have investigated the error further and it seems to be connected to the ion-content component.

Comment: I didn't really think it would fix the problem but it's for the best that you upgraded. It's one of the reasons I'm heavily distrustful of boilerplates I didn't realize that that was the cause here but it compounds my sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

Even the latest ionic version does only use Angular 5.0.0. Change your dependencies to the following:

```
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.0",
  "rxjs": "5.5.2",
  "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  ...
},
"devDependencies: {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0"
  "typescript" : "2.4.2"
}
```

1. Now delete the folder node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json or yarn.lock (if you're using yarn).
3. Then run npm install or yarn install (if you're using yarn again).

One more important thing: Make sure you use the latest **LTS** node version: Currently it's 8.9.4.

Comment: I changed my dependencies to the version numbers suggested and updated Node. It did not solve the problem. I still get the Cannot read property 'children' of null error.

Comment: The issue can't seem to be reproduced from the piece of code you gave us.

Comment: The error seems to be connected to NavController. If I remove all references to that I don't get the error any more.